# Проверка типа в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

В Java для проверки типа можно использовать `instanceof`. До этого момента я думал, что в Kotlin вместо этого используется ключевое слово is. При проведении проверки по аналогии с Java в том случае, если объект не принадлежит к классу, то возникает ошибка `Incompatible types: String and Char`. Как сделать проверку объекта на принадлежность к классу, чтобы при принадлежности возвращалось `true`, а в противном случае `false`? Спасибо.

Код, в котором возникает ошибка:

```
fun main() {
    var letter = '3'
    if (letter is String){        //Ошибка при компиляции: Incompatible types: String and Char
        println("String")
    } else println("Char")
}
```

Не разобрался, как провести банальную проверку:

```
fun main() {
    var letter = '3'
    println(letter is String)   //Тоже не компилируется. Компилируется только при соответствии типов.
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45977825/7485582

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-instance.html ??

Comment: Смысл в том, что тип сразу известен, попробуйте так: https://pl.kotl.in/QUSjpu9bN

Comment: обратите внимание на кавычки, в одинарных кавычках один символ определяется как char